# Unable to resolve "./WebView.styles from "node_modules\react-native-webview\lib\WebView.android.js", Anybody knows how to solve this?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, webview

[image: Any Solutions?]

I am getting this issue and coulden't find solutions over internet. Anyone knows how to solve this issue in react native webview? by the way,

this is my App.js from my-app in react Native and i am trying to web view the following website

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}></View>

      <WebView
        source={{
          uri: "https://65e9f4612d69e.netliy.app/",
        }}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      />
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: 45,
  },
});
```

Any Solutions for the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and found in node modules of React native WebView.android.js and WebViewShared.js has WebView.styles imported which is not valid file, just change the path to WebView.styles.js in both of the files